# How to send different subscription response based on condition in GraphQL (NestJS)?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, publish-subscribe, subscription

I would like to send to clients different subscription response, based on some condition. `withFilter` filter and send response only when condition is met. I want to send two different response based on some condition - map response, based on condition. Is there any `withMap` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could use the [`resolve`](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/subscriptions#mutating-subscription-payloads) property and map the rsponse from within that.

Example from the docs:

```js
@Subscription(returns => Comment, {
  resolve(this: AuthorResolver, value) {
    // "this" refers to an instance of "AuthorResolver"
    return value;
  }
})
commentAdded() {
  return pubSub.asyncIterator('commentAdded');
}
```

Comment: Thank You, thats what I looking for.